# Query acting extremely slow

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this query on a Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production that is extremely slow (**Fetched 50 rows in 3.859 seconds**) and I don't know what else to do to optimize it!
t_operation has only **12610 rows** !

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "IOT"."V_DEVICES_LIST" ( "PRODUCT", "DEVICE_LIST") AS 
select
  PRODUCT ,
  RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, NAME,', ').EXTRACT('//text()')  ).GetClobVal(),',') AS DEVICE_LIST
from
   t_operation 
where   
   discriminator = 'ANDROID'  and product is not null 
group by
  PRODUCT;
```

EXPLAIN PLAN :

```
EXPLAIN PLAN 
  SET statement_id = 'ex_plan1' FOR
 select
      PRODUCT ,
      RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, NAME,', ').EXTRACT('//text()')  ).GetClobVal(),',') AS DEVICE_LIST
    from
       t_operation 
    where   
       discriminator = 'ANDROID'  and product is not null 
    group by
      PRODUCT;
```

result:

```
Plan hash value: 795775875

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             | 11484 |   246K|    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |             | 11484 |   246K|    11  (19)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_OPERATION | 11992 |   257K|     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("PRODUCT" IS NOT NULL AND "DISCRIMINATOR"='ANDROID')

Note
-----
   - Unoptimized XML construct detected (enable XMLOptimizationCheck for more information)
```

AND T_OPERATION:

```
 CREATE TABLE "IOT"."T_OPERATION" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DISCRIMINATOR" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COUNTRY" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COMPUTER" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "PRODUCT" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "ADDRESS" NUMBER(38,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_OPR_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 655360 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "IOT"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_OPR2ADR_INF" FOREIGN KEY ("ADDRESS")
      REFERENCES "IOT"."T_ADDRESS_INFO" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_OPR2CTR" FOREIGN KEY ("COUNTRY")
      REFERENCES "IOT"."T_COUNTRY" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_OPR2PRD" FOREIGN KEY ("PRODUCT")
      REFERENCES "IOT"."T_TABLET" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_OPR2SRV" FOREIGN KEY ("COMPUTER")
      REFERENCES "IOT"."T_COMPUTER" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 2097152 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "IOT" ;

  CREATE INDEX "IOT"."V_DEVICES_LIST_3" ON "IOT"."T_OPERATION" (UPPER("NAME")) 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "IOT" ;
```

Comment: How large is the table? How slow is "*slow*"?

Comment: What does the explain plan look like? have statistics been updated on this table? are there indexes (being utilized)?

Comment: Can you add the predicate information from the execution plan output too please? Everything that `dbms_xplan.display` showed. How many rows in your table have `ANDROID`, and how many of those have a not-null product?

Comment: OK, then I don't think it's anything to do with access (so an index won't help - looks like you're getting the vast majority of rows, about 11k of 12k?), it's the XML creation and aggregation that's slow. I had a quick go with a user-defined aggregate function but that was also slow. There is just a lot of data to process, and CLOBs (and XMLTypes, which are similar) seem to have a lot of overhead.

Comment: Of course, there's an assumption here that you're expecting your CSV lists to exceed 4K and are doing this because you can't use `listagg()`; how many distinct products does your query find, and what's the maximum (current) length of the generated `device_list` values? If you can have more than 16 names per products then you'd risk exceeding 4K. Just need to rule out the obvious...

Comment: The `name` column is just 255 bytes.... so wondering how there could be so much overhead on a small value. I'm curious how many rows the query returns in real life; if table statistics shown in the explain plan are correct and up to date, then yes, an index I suggested below won't help.  Please let the query run to completion to see how many rows it actually returns.  Sometimes the table statistics are out of date.

Comment: @MarkStewart - the overhead is from the CLOB handling, not the individual 255-byte names. And the CLOB is needed if there can be 16 names for a product, as those plus the delimiters could exceed 4096 bytes. With listagg or other varchar2 aggregation techniques (with few/short enough names to not break the limit) it's fast; from my testing the dramatic slow-down is when you switch to CLOBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Retrieving the data from the table is going as fast as it can - as your filter doesn't seem to be very selective a full table scan is probably going to be suitable anyway, and adding an index is unlikely to help. With that volume of data that is going to be relatively fast anyway.

The time is being spent in the aggregation. I tried using XMLQuery instead of `extract()` (as that is deprecated) but it was slower, if anything. I also tried with a user-defined CLOB aggregator, and the `collect()` method ([see this popular list of techniques](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)), and they were also a bit slower. Of course that's on my system and with the test data I made up; your results might vary but these alternatives don't seem likely to give you significant gains.

If your aggregated lists of names can exceed 4K - which might only take 17 names per product - then you can't use `listagg()`, and presumably what's why you're trying to use XMLAgg in the first place.

Unfortunately it seems you just have to live with the overhead that involves, form the XMLType and CLOB manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Put an index on `discriminator` and `product` columns:

```
create index i_operation_disc_prod on t_operation(discriminator, product);
```

Assuming that `discriminator='ANDROID'` yields less than 10% of the number of rows in table `t_operation`.

Comment: I think this index improves the PLAN and execution then is improved.

Comment: @MarkStewart - IOT seems to be the schema and tablespace name, rather than indicating it's actually an index-organised table, if that's what you meant?

Comment: Oops!  @AlexPoole you are right; I'll edit my answer.  I saw IOT and my mind expanded that to `organization index` !